# jQuery Ajax and Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to ask, how to do some thing:

I have a Wordpress for example twentyten theme.
I have its functions.php but on the end I'm including my functions using:

```
require_once('my_functions.php');
```

It works :)

Now, I want to make an ajax call using jQuery, but php function which I want to call is using wordpress global vars. For example $post and others. Also function that I want to call is connecting to database, so if I make a call using url: my_functions.php this global vars will not be working. Also the connection to database I will have to create.

Question is: how to do it with all Wordpress variables included.

It looks like my file is out of Wordpress Environment, but how to create my custom files that will be able to use Wp Environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Ajax is a thing you are searching for:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_$handlename', 'function_to_run');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_$handlename', 'function_to_run');
```

Function to run will response to your ajax request.

Also, you will need:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery-theme.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION, false );
$protocol = isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$params = array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', $protocol )  );
wp_localize_script( 'theme_js', 'theme_js', $params );
```

when including your custom js, so it knows, where it should search for php file that responds to wp_ajax request.

Now, with ajaxurl You can $.post with jQuery and get answer.